# Synergy config being shared across computers

Tags: synergy, profile

For some reason, I am unable to change where my synergy 1.3.1 profile data is being stored. With the result that when I start up, both computers end up reading it from the same shared file.

Effectively this means that I'm ending up with both computers acting as clients or servers and both with the same name, until I change their profiles manually.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried uninstalling Synergy and then reinstalling?  If you haven't done so, try deleting the config file and starting over with your setup configuration.

Some suggestions to easier control your computers:

If you're running Windows only systems, then consider [Input Director](http://www.inputdirector.com/), which is more stable and has an easier GUI.

If you are using multiple operating systems, consider upgrading to [Synergy+](http://code.google.com/p/synergy-plus/), which is a newer version of Synergy.

For an easier GUI version of Synergy, check out [QSynergy](http://lifehacker.com/5515093/qsynergy-makes-multi+system-control-easier-and-prettier).  via Lifehacker.